# PyQt: Reorder tabs in QTabWidget

Tags: save, pyqt, qtabwidget

I made my GUI using Qt Designer and I have a QTabWidget with multiple tabs. My tabs contain specific tools that are used in my app. Now I would like to set my tabs closable and movable so I could save the order of my tabs and load it when the app starts. The problem is, I don't know how to reorder my tabs when the application loads. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can move tabs by accessing the `QTabBar` object associated with the `QTabQidget`

`QTabBar` has a method `moveTab()` which will allow you to reorder tabs.

So you would do something like `my_tab_widget.tabBar().moveTab(old_position, new_position)` where `old_position` and `new_position` are integers which specify the tab to move and the position to move it to respectively.

Lots of details in the c++ documentation (it translates to python pretty easily). See [QTabBar docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qtabbar.html) and [QTabWidget docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html)

Comment: Thank you, I will try that out when I get home =)

Comment: Works like a charm. Now I just have to save and load the tab order =)